# How to display username and invoked api name in wso2 apim log?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure gateway access log of wso2 apim (4.0.0) so that it should contain api username and api name in a log file. I followed [this documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/monitoring-http-access-logs/).

The log file structure I would like to have as below:

datetime | remoteIp | username | invoked_api_name | api_url | request | response

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The `invoked_api_name` and `username` are not available at the Access Log level. Therefore, you can implement a custom Synapse Handler to log the relevant information to either `wso2carbon.log` or separate logs as per your need. This is a sample written for API Manager 3.2.0 [Custom API Log Handler](https://github.com/athiththan11/Custom-API-Log-Handler)

Comment: I followed the instruction in the readme file, but I have no result. I checked synapse-handlers.xml file for existence of corresponding handler, it wasn't appended. Even after mannually adding that synapse handler to the synapse-handlers.xml, it keeps disappearing right after restarting the apim server

Comment: Here is my synapse-handlers.xml file:
`<handlers xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">`
    `<handler name="external_call_logger" class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.LogsHandler"/>`
    `<handler name="external_call_logger" class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.DefaultAPIHandler"/>`
    `<handler name="open_tracing" class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.common.APIMgtLatencySynapseHandler"/>`
`</handlers>`

Comment: Adding the Handler directly to the `synapse-handlers.xml` will not work. The APIM 4.0.0 uses a centralized configuration called `deployment.toml` to configure the product. Therefore, if you add any configurations directly to the XML, those will get overridden during the startup. I have added an answer below with the correct configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `invoked_api_name` and `username` are not available at the Access Log level. Therefore, you can implement a custom Synapse Handler to log the relevant information to either `wso2carbon.log` or separate logs as per your need.

This is a sample written for API Manager 3.2.0 [Custom API Log Handler](https://github.com/athiththan11/Custom-API-Log-Handler). You can also refer to the Handler mentioned by [@Ishara Cooray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68131579/10269117).

Update the dependencies to align with the API Manager 4.0.0 environment. The TOML configuration to engage the Handlers will be as following (it is slightly different from the configs in 3.2.0)

```
[synapse_handlers.<custom_name>]
enabled = true
class = '<package-name.class>'
```

For example

```
[synapse_handlers.api_log_handler]
enabled = true
class = 'com.sample.handlers.APILogHandler'
```

---

**Update**

I have updated the custom handler implementation with API Manager 4.0.0 dependencies. Find the branch and updated `README` [here](https://github.com/athiththan11/Custom-API-Log-Handler/tree/4.0.0).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly.
If I want to extract api username, is this correct way to do this?
`String userName= (String)messageContext.getProperty("USERNAME");`

Comment: You can use the following property to extract the username: `api.ut.userName`. The complete code will be as: `(String) messageContext.getProperty("api.ut.userName");`

Comment: Is it possible to obtain user profile info as well?

Comment: Yes, we can. But this will be a costly task. We can get the User profile information using the OpenID scope while generating the JWT Token, or we have to enable the X-JWT-Assertion and write a custom implementation to retrieve claims related to specific user.

Comment: Is it possible to change time zone, because it is printing by default UTC?

Answer (score 1):

you are not be able to include username in the access_log as this information is not available at this level.
You may write a custom handler to log the required information in a log file.
https://github.com/CrowleyRajapakse/CustomLogHandler

Comment: I followed the instruction in the readme file, but I have no result. I checked synapse-handlers.xml file for existence of corresponding handler, it wasn't appended. Even after mannually adding that synapse handler to the synapse-handlers.xml, it keeps disappearing right after restarting the apim server