# How to add custom log file for every day entries in wso2 apim?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am trying to configure gateway access log of wso2 apim (4.0.0) to be written to a separate log file every day so that it should contain api username and api name in a log file. To form the structure of the log file I followed the answer of [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119383/how-to-display-username-and-invoked-api-name-in-wso2-apim-log/68158789?noredirect=1#comment120468973_68158789).

The log file structure I have as below:

datetime | remoteIp | username | invoked_api_name | api_url | request | response

Now all entries is being written in wso2carbon.log

I would like it to be written in a file with following pattern:

*custom_access_log_gwyyyy-mm-dd.log*

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce an extra Log Appender to log the specific Handler logs in it. Find sample instructions below

- Open the `<apim>/repository/conf/log4j2.properties` and add the following to create a Log Appender

  ```
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.type = RollingFile
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.name = APIHANDLER_LOG
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.fileName = ${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/api-log.log
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.filePattern = ${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/api-log-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.layout.type = PatternLayout
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.layout.pattern = TID: [%tenantId] [%appName] [%d] %5p {%c} - %m%ex%n
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.policies.type = Policies
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.policies.time.interval = 1
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.policies.time.modulate = true
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.policies.size.size=10MB
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.strategy.max = 20
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
  appender.APIHANDLER_LOG.filter.threshold.level = DEBUG
  ```
- Add the created Appender to the `appenders` property at the top of the `log4j2.properties`

  ```
  appenders=APIHANDLER_LOG, CARBON_CONSOLE, ..
  ```
- Configure your package to log into the new Appender

  ```
  logger.api-log-handler.name = com.sample.handlers.APILogHandler
  logger.api-log-handler.level = DEBUG
  logger.api-log-handler.appenderRef.APIHANDLER_LOG.ref = APIHANDLER_LOG
  logger.api-log-handler.additivity = false
  ```

  ```
  loggers = api-log-handler, AUDIT_LOG, ...
  ```

Save the configurations and invoke the API. Now the logs will be printed to a file called `api-log.log`.

Comment: If I add some modification to the code APILogHandler, the structure of the api-log.log file keeps remaining unchanged. What should I do?

Comment: What sort of changes did you make to the Handler? Can you elaborate more on what you are referring to as the structures of the log? If you have made changes to the Handler package names or have revamped the class Names, then you have to remove the `OSGi` bundle (automatically generated during startup) from the `components/dropins` directory. After removal, add the new JAR to the `components/lib` directory and restart the server.

Comment: Thanks. Now the changes have been applied