# How to display profile info of the user that called certain api in wso2 apim log?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure gateway access log of wso2 apim (4.0.0) so that it should contain profile info (for ex: organization, email) of the user that called certain api along with the owner of that api in a log file. I followed the answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119383/how-to-display-username-and-invoked-api-name-in-wso2-apim-log)

The structure that I would like to have is:

username | user_organization | invoked_api_name | api_owner | api_url | request | response

Any help is welcome!

Comment: I can think of 2 approaches. One is generating the JWT token with OpenID scope to include user claims. Then extract the claims from the JWT Token in the Handler and append those. Second is enable the X-JWT-Assertion, and develop a custom JWT Generator to add the custom claims to the Assertion Token. Then capture that token in the Handler and extract those. Not, that these approaches will add an overhead to the API invocation, as we are trying to perform the extraction and extra steps.

Comment: Actually, my final goal is to prepare raw data for statistics as a log file. Even if I obtain that structure, afterwards I have to parse it. I know there is a solution out of box like analytics. But since apim 4.0.0, it is moved to the cloud. In my case I am not allowed to move all the statistics to the cloud.

Comment: Got it. In this case, what do you mean by `user_organization`? Are you referring to the Tenant Domain name? or something else?

Comment: By user_organization I am referring to the organization that user belongs. It is in the profile of the user. The user is the one who made a request to the api.

Comment: I have briefed two options to achieve it in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the following properties, we can extract the `API Publisher`, `Username`, and `Tenant Domain` from the Message Context in the custom Handler.

```xml
api.ut.apiPublisher: API Publisher
api.ut.userId: Username
```

Perform the following enhancements to the `handleRequestOutFlow(..)` method in the [Custom Handler](https://github.com/athiththan11/Custom-API-Log-Handler/tree/4.0.0) to extract the mentioned data

```java
public boolean handleRequestOutFlow(..) {
    ...
    String username = (String) messageContext.getProperty("api.ut.userId");
    String apiCreator = (String) messageContext.getProperty("api.ut.apiPublisher");
    String apiContext = (String) messageContext.getProperty("api.ut.context");
    String tenantDomain = MultitenantUtils.getTenantDomainFromRequestURL(apiContext);
    if (tenantDomain == null) {
        tenantDomain = org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy.MultitenantConstants.SUPER_TENANT_DOMAIN_NAME;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

#### Update

If you want to log the `organization` of a User via the custom Handler, then I can think of two options to achieve the requirement.

- **Option 01: Configure OpenID Scope**

  > This option is applicable if you are having only a handful of applications that are needed for this function.

  Configure an additional OpenID scope mapping to the `organization` claim via the Carbon Management console. And make the `organization` claim a mandatory claim at each Service Provider to generate the JWT Access Token including the `organization` claim.

  When you are trying to generate the Token, you have to pass the OpenID scope that we have created for the `organization`, so that the Service Provider will evaluate and include the claim in the Token.

  Once the token arrives at the Gateway via the Headers, capture the token and extract the claim from it. Or else, configure the Gateway node to generate the X-JWT-Assertion token and capture that token and extract the claim.
- **Option 02: Customize the Handler to retrieve claims**

  We can enhance the Handler implementation to extract the Username from the JWT Access Token and then invoke a set of Key Manager endpoints with the required properties to retrieve the User claims. You can check the [Key Manager connector implementation](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/apim-km-wso2is) to find the relative endpoints to retrieve the User claims.

Hope this briefing helps you to choose a path. In addition, I have added few enhancements to the [custom handler](https://github.com/athiththan11/Custom-API-Log-Handler/tree/4.0.0) implementation focusing on the 2nd option.

Comment: Let's assume that an api is deployed by admin, but the owner of it is some organization. It can be specified in business info section of publisher. Is it possible to add Api owner to log file?

Comment: Then, without using the `api.ut.apiPublisher` property to get the value (which will be `admin` as per your example), we have to retrieve the Organization this user belongs to. With that, you should be able to print the Organization as the Owner of the API. Further, during runtime, the message context will not have any information related to Business Info configured via Publisher. Therefore, we have to enhance to retrieve those as per the needs.

Comment: According to readme in https://github.com/athiththan11/Custom-API-Log-Handler/tree/4.0.0, in log file it should be displayed correlationId but it doesn't.  How can I get correlationId?

Comment: In order to get the `correlation-ID` in the logs, you have to enable the observability logs in the API Manager Server. You can find more information from [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/api-manager/monitoring-correlation-logs/). The correlation ID is generated and used to track the process and APIs only when the observability logs are enabled at the API Manager level.