# How to display correlationId, request payload and response body when certain api was in wso2 apim log

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am trying to write custom api log handler for wso2 apim (4.0.0) so that it should add correlationId,  request payload and response body when certain api is called. I followed the answer to similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68361565/how-to-display-profile-info-of-the-user-that-called-certain-api-in-wso2-apim-log/68383156). So far I have done following:

```
public boolean handleRequestOutFlow(..) {
    ...
    String uuIdHeader = (String) messageContext.getProperty("CORRELATION_ID_HEADER");
    if (tenantDomain == null) {
        tenantDomain = org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy.MultitenantConstants.SUPER_TENANT_DOMAIN_NAME;
    }
    ...
}
```

But uuIdHeader keeps returning null.

Any hint is appreciated on how to get correlationId, request payload and response body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlation ID is generated when Observability logs are enabled in the API Manager server.

Therefore, to get the `correlation-id` printed in your logs, you have to enable the observability logs as instructed in [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/api-manager/monitoring-correlation-logs/). You can get more insights about the observability logs and correlation IDs in [the official Docs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/api-manager/monitoring-correlation-logs/).

Comment: What about intercepting request and response body from message context?

Comment: Main idea, I would like to intercept correlation Id, username, request and response body in order to be aware of which user requested what and received what

Comment: As mentioned in the shared docs, if the request has any unique UUID values mentioned in the request header as `activityid`, then that can be used to correlate the requests and responses in the API Manager platform. In order to track a request and response end-to-end, we might need a unique value to be sent as mentioned.

Comment: Yes, thanks to your help, now I have got activityId. The only missing parts are request and response body themselves.

Comment: Is it possible to acquire request and response from messageContext like messageContext.getProperty("SOME_PROPERTY_REQUEST_PAYLOAD")?

Comment: I have looked up some references according to which it is messageContext.getProperty("JSON_OBJECT"). But not sure if it is indeed

Comment: You can follow this [sample](https://github.com/athiththan11/Revamp-Mediator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/athiththan/sample/CustomMediator.java#L15-L24) to extract your payloads from the message context.